# Split a string after a word with up to 20 characters on a line

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program which will split a user input of a very long sentence which every 20 characters, a new line is created. If the end of the 20 characters is in the middle of a word, it will print the previous full word

```
using System;

namespace stringToLines
{
    class Program
    {
        static void split()
        {
            string sent = Console.ReadLine();
            int a = sent.Length / 20;
            string[] line;

            int space = sent.IndexOf(' ');
            while (space < 20)
            {
                int i = 0;
                line[i] = sent.Substring(0, space);
                sent = sent.Substring(space, sent.Length-space);
                space = sent.IndexOf(' ');
                i++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <=a; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line[i],"\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            return split;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your long sentence(>20 characters)");

            split();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could improve performance by getting rid of the `sent = send.Substring(space, sent.Length-space);` and providing a `startIndex` when you do `sent.IndexOf(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ask a very clear question.
I read that you want to break an entered text into lines that are a maximum of 20 characters long, but you don't want to break into a word itself.
If that's your question, (then change the title of your question like this: 'Split a string after a word with up to 20 characters on a line ' so that others can find it but) you can use the solution below:

Change your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your long sentence(>20 characters)");

    var sent = Console.ReadLine();
    var lines = sent.SplitOnLastWhiteSpaceAt(20);

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lines[i], "\n");
    }

    Console.ReadLine("Press any key to close");
}
```

Use this string extension methode:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace stackoverflow.question_69882038.Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string[] SplitOnLastWhiteSpaceAt(this string value, int maxLength)
        {
            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                var _rest = value;

                while (_rest.Length > maxLength)
                {
                    for (var i = maxLength; i >= 0; i += -1)
                    {
                        //Start on end, Search last index of WhiteSpace
                        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(_rest[i]))
                        {
                            values.Add(_rest.Substring(0, i));
                            if (i > _rest.Length)
                                return values.ToArray();
                            //Last item is not Empty or WithSpace
                            _rest = _rest.Substring(i + 1);
                            //Remove the WithSpace where splitted on
                            break;
                            //No Whitespace was found. Split on maxLenght.
                        }
                        else if (i == 0)
                        {
                            values.Add(_rest.Substring(0, maxLength));
                            _rest = _rest.Substring(maxLength);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (_rest.Length > 1 || (_rest.Length > 0 && !char.IsWhiteSpace(_rest[0])))
                    values.Add(_rest);
                //Last item is not 1 Char as Empty or WithSpace

                return values.ToArray();
            }
            finally
            {
                values.Clear();
                value = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I know, this code could be better. Take out what you need. Basically it will work.